# Передача объекта при нажатии на виджет

Tags: python, qt5, pyside2

Пример создал для простоты и понимания, на деле, конечно, передаются не объекты кнопок.

Нужно вот что, при нажатии на виджет (в примере это кнопки), объект виджета передавался бы в другой "принимающий" виджет, и он показывал некоторую информацию которая хранилась в объекте (в примере это текст кнопки).

Проблема в чём (буду описывать на примере): когда коннектишь кнопки вручную то работает всё как надо - в "принимающем" виджете показывается текст той кнопки, которую нажал.  Но кнопок "много", нужен цикл, и тут всё работает не так как ожидалось, при нажатии ЛЮЮБОЙ кнопки в "принимающем" виджете показывается текст только последней кнопки (которая коннектилась в последней итерации).

В чём может быть проблема?
Может есть какие-то другие способы передачи объекта в "принимающий" виджет?

Пример кода:

```
import sys

from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtCore import *


class Main_window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Main_window, self).__init__();

        self.main_wgt = QWidget();
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_wgt);


        left_grid = QVBoxLayout();
        btn = [];
        for i in range(3):
            btn.append(QPushButton(str(i)));
            left_grid.addWidget(btn[i]);

        right_wgt = Right_wgt();

        main_grid = QHBoxLayout();
        main_grid.addLayout(left_grid);
        main_grid.addWidget(right_wgt);

        self.main_wgt.setLayout(main_grid);


        # Если вручную добавлять всё работает как надо
        # btn[0].clicked.connect(lambda: right_wgt.slot(btn[0]))
        # btn[1].clicked.connect(lambda: right_wgt.slot(btn[1]))
        # btn[2].clicked.connect(lambda: right_wgt.slot(btn[2]))

        # Если циклом то передаётся только последнее значение
        for i in range(len(btn)):
            btn[i].clicked.connect(lambda: right_wgt.slot(btn[i]))



class Right_wgt(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Right_wgt, self).__init__();

        self.setFixedSize(100, 100);
        self.setStyleSheet("background:#ddd");

        self.label = QLabel("default");
        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.addWidget(self.label);

        self.setLayout(grid);

    def slot(self, item):
        self.label.setText(item.text())
        print(item);





if ( __name__ == "__main__" ):
    app = QApplication(sys.argv);
    window = Main_window();
    window.show();
    sys.exit(app.exec_());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А если так:

```
btn[i].clicked.connect(lambda state, idx=i: right_wgt.slot(btn[idx]))
```

Comment: TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'state'

Comment: А если без `state` то всё наоборот получается, показывается текст только первой кнопки

Comment: А если присвоить `state` какое либо значение, то всё работает как надо! `btn[i].clicked.connect(lambda state = 0, idx = i: right_wgt.slot(btn[idx]))`  Но мне непонятно как это работает и почему именно так?

Comment: @froxxendsg Я добавил state потому что у батоновского кликеда есть аргумент булевского типа, а второй параметр это локальная переменная для каждой лямбды, в которую копируется текущее значение внешнего i, иначе лямбды ссылаются на один и тот же внешний объект. Странно, что state надо инициализировать, там по-умолчанию false передаётся. Завтра сам все проверю.

Comment: На одномерном массиве (list в Python то есть) Ваш пример работает как надо, но в двумерном начинается почти то же самое, последний массив с коннектами работает как надо, а вот первые = точные копии последнего массива, уже не знаю как бороться с этим, вручную писать всё не айс.  (у меня календарь, и по клику на число (свой виджет) в "принимающий" виджет должен посылаться объект этого "числа" чтобы отобразить инфу, соотв. массив состоит из месяцев, а месяц = тоже массив - из дней)

Comment: @froxxendsg для двумерного случая не забывайте, что в каждой лямбде должны быть локальные значения номера строки и столбца. lambda state=0, localRow=externalRow, localCol=externalCol:... Должно работать

Comment: Само собой не забыл, конструкция которая отображает 1 месяц - работает, а вот весь год - нет (я неправильно выразился изначально, у меня двумерный массив 3*4 который содержит объекты месяцев, каждый месяц - двумерный массив 7*6 содержащий объекты дней месяца, и надо чтобы при клике на день его объект передавался в другой виджет (выводящий инфу), с Вашим кодом последний месяц работает как надо, но предыдущие - копируют последний (похоже на пример из сабжа), я уже все мозги сломал как это нормально реализовать..

Comment: @froxxendsg все тоже самое, что и ранее надо помнить о том чтобы не утянуть внешние общие данные. Но надо отдохнуть, отвлечься от задачи, чтобы пыль (новое знание) в голове улеглась и прояснилось.)

Comment: Всё решилось благополучно, но другим способом, без лямбд, благодаря статье, которую я успешно уже успел потерять :(  Столько часов работы дают о себе знать  Но я всё ещё не понимаю почему оно работало не так как задумывалось XD

Comment: UPD: Вот статья - https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Python_Signals_and_Slots

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89951/discussion-between-alexander-chernin-and-froxxendsg).